# Append To Multi-dimensional array where matching matching another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, matching

I have two arrays:

```
a = [
  [a, b],
  [c, d],
  [e, f],
  [g, h]
]

b = [
  [a, 4],
  [1, 2],
  [e, 3]
]
```

when `a[i][0]`, matches `b[i][0]`, I need to add a value to the current index of a. For this example, when `a[0][1]` matches `b[0][1]`, `a[0][1]` should look like `[a,b,new_value]`.

If this means creating a new array with all of the values of `a`, that is fine, but the original values and order of `a` cannot change.

I have tried numerous variations of for loops and reverse for loops. I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add the result as well.

Comment: If you could give us a fully formed result for your example, that'd help a lot coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too bad with a map + find. For each item of the `a` array, see if there is a matching element in the `b` array, and if so, add your new value:

```js
const a = [
  ["a","b"],
  ["c","d"],
  ["e","f"],
  ["g","h"],
];

const b = [
  ["a",4],
  [1,2],
  ["e",3],
];

const mapped = a.map(x => {
  const match = b.find(y => y[0] === x[0]);
  if (match) return [...x, "new value"] // Replace "new value" with whatever you want to add...
  return x;
});

console.log(mapped)
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the 1st array with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Compare each sub array's 1st item to a sub array in the 2nd array at the same index. If they match, [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) a value to the sub array from the 1st array, and return it. If not, return the sub array.

**Note:** concat and map create new arrays, and don't change the original.

```js
var a = [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"],["g","h"]];

var b = [["a",4],[1,2],["e",3]];
     
var result = a.map(function(item, i) {
  return b[i] && item[0] === b[i][0] ? item.concat(b[i][1]) : item; // replace b[i][1] with whatever value you want to add
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the result of the check by using a default value, if the length of the given arrays are different.

```js
var array1 = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']],
    array2 = [['a', 4], [1, 2], ['e', 3]],
    result = array1.map((a, i) => a.concat(a[0] === (array2[i] || [])[0] ? array2[i][1] : []));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```